# how to commit in git?

Tags: git

I am new to git and while trying to commit I got the following message:

```
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
Author identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got '91949@PC.(none)')"
```

How do I get my file committed?

Comment: The answer is in the question. Did you run the `git config` commands?

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions on that error message? It's telling you to run those two commands because it needs to get your Git identity.

Comment: Run those pair of suggested commands to set your name and email, then run your commit command again after that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the text returned by the command:

> Run
>
> git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
> git config --global user.name "Your Name"

Run one of those, supplying either your email or your name and git should be happy to let you commit.